# Saving the textview background color that has been changed dynamically

Tags: android

I have 2 activities A and B. I have a button in A. When I click on the button in A I am taken to Activity B. Activity B has a textview. The scenario is when I click on the text view in B, its background color should change to red. I am able to do this. But when I press back button -> Goto Activity A -> Then again press the button to come to Activity B - The red background color is gone.

I want to save the background color for ever, i.e. once if I click on the textview and change its background color, its background color should save that value no matter I switch between activities or close the app and restart it. Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: When the user click TextView, save the status in SharedPreferences, then read the status from SharedPreferences in the method onCreate of Activity B and set background. That's a simple solution, you may need SQLite when facing more data.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences would solve your problem :

examples here:

[exmple 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946292/pick-a-color-from-the-holocolorpicker-then-saved-using-shared-preferences)

[exmple2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368725/android-shared-preferences-mcolorpicker-issue)

Answer (score 0):

In Activity B, use SharedPrefrences inside to get previous value **onCreate()**.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isAlreadyRed = prefs.getBoolean("isRed",false);
if(isRed){
   //button color change logic
}
```

Inside onClick() for your button, put below code.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isRed", true);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save it permanently then you can use SharedPreferences or sqlite, or if you want to save the color while app is running only then in this case you can save the hex value of color in any class variable or you can store it in application level.